# Warning Implicit conversion loses integer precision

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
//getIndividualWords(..) basically splits a sentence based on a specified delimiter: here delimiter is SPACE

vector<string> getIndividualWords(string line, string delimiter)
{
    int startingPosition = 0, endingPosition = 0, delimiterLength = delimiter.length();

    string words;
    vector<string> wordList; //stores all the words received by splitting the sentence

    while ((endingPosition = line.find (delimiter, startingPosition)) != string::npos) //the loop continues till it finds SPACES in the sentence
    {
        words = line.substr (startingPosition, endingPosition - startingPosition);
        startingPosition = endingPosition + delimiterLength;
        wordList.push_back (words);
    }

    wordList.push_back (line.substr (startingPosition)); //inserts the words into a vector container
    return wordList;
}
```

And I am getting this warning:

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision

Comment: `delimiter.length();` yields `size_t` which is usually `unsigned long`.

Comment: ...... what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

All of the `std::string` methods that deal with sizes and indexes operate on `std::string::size_type` values, not `int` values.  The `size_type` is usually `std::size_t`, which is an *unsigned* integer.  Converting an unsigned integer to a signed integer can lose precision.

So, `startingPosition`, `endingPosition`, and `delimiterLength` need to be declared as `std::string::size_type` to match what `std::string` actually uses.

Try this:

```
vector<string> getIndividualWords(const string &line, const string &delimiter)
{
    string::size_type startingPosition = 0, endingPosition, delimiterLength = delimiter.length();
    string words;
    vector<string> wordList;

    while ((endingPosition = line.find (delimiter, startingPosition)) != string::npos)
    {
        words = line.substr (startingPosition, endingPosition - startingPosition);
        startingPosition = endingPosition + delimiterLength;
        wordList.push_back (words);
    }

    if (startingPosition < line.length())
        wordList.push_back (line.substr (startingPosition));

    return wordList;
}
```